# Satellite image in ArcGIS darker than usual

Tags: landsat-8, satellite, digital-image-processing

This is one image from 2013 in some área.
[image]

This is another image from 2014 in the same área, but darker. why? How can I display it like in 2013.

[image]

Both are Landsat 8 images.

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm whether the images themselves are darker or they are just darker in ArcGIS.  For ArcGIS Desktop:  Layer Properties->Symbology Tab->Stretch-> change ‘Type’ to None (for both images).  Also confirm that the Channel/Band combinations are the same for both images.  This should show you the images in their more raw form.

I suspect the color won’t be exactly balanced since they are different images.  You can play around with the Stretch settings until you get them similar enough for your tastes. Or research some color balance other image processing techniques to get them closer.

Comment: Both images with type "none" on are different, being the 2013 one almost black (nothing can be differentiated) and the 2014 one a little bit white (you can differentiate the relief).

Comment: the images shown before are with the percent clip type on

Comment: They are different images so we should expect some differences.  If you need them to 'look' similar you will have to play around with each image's symbology to get them to match.  You can also process the images using digital image processing techniques like color balance to get something more aesthetically pleasing to you.  There should be plenty of info on that, if not ask a question asking about those specifics.

Comment: Viewing the histograms of each image will also demonstrate how these are different and how they are similar.  Attempting to stretch an image to match the other's histogram is one way to balance the color.